# LINUX FIFO named pipe (IPC) stops writing/reading message at specific file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc

I'm communicating between two non-related process (not folked from the same parent) using Named Pipe (fifo mode).
The program works. However, the pile file seem to be limited

The OUTPUT of the writer:

```
Wrote to file. fd = 3
Wrote to file. fd = 3
...... other output ...
Wrote to file. fd = 3
Wrote to file. fd = 3
```

The OUTPUT of the reader is:

```
fd: 3. Received buffer: hello
fd: 4. Received buffer: hello
...... other output ...
fd: 1021. Received buffer: hello
fd: 1022. Received buffer: hello
fd: 1023. Received buffer: hello
```

MY PROBLEM: At `fd` 1023, the reader seems to STOP READING from file (there is no `fd` 1024, 1025, etc.). When it happens, the writer STOP WRITING (log "Wrote to file. fd = 3" stops display)

I try different `msg` value ("hi", "where are you" ...), but the writer always stop at `fd` 1023

I really don't understand why. Could you explain for me?
Thanks you so much!

Here is my code:
The writer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit functions */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, pipe, _exit */
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char msg[] = "hello";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        return;
    }

    while(1) {
        write(fd, msg, sizeof(msg));
        printf("Wrote to file. fd = %d\n", fd);
        sleep(1);
    }
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

The reader:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 500

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    while(1) {
        /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

        if (fd != -1) {
            if (read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) {
                printf("fd: %d. Received buffer: %s\n", fd, buf);
            }
        }
        sleep(0.2);
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep calling `open` in a loop? You do not need to do that to use the pipe, and there is a limit on the number of open files you can have at one time.

Answer (score 1):

> I really don't understand why. Could you explain for me?

There's a limit on the number of open file descriptors on your system. The limit can be checked in shell with `ulimit -n`. It is configurable. See `help ulimit` and `man limits.conf`.

On your system the maximum number of open file descriptors seems to be at 1024 (on mine too!) Opening more will return `-1` with `errno=EMFILE`.

Your `reader` program opens new file descriptors in a loop. After reaching the limit of open file descriptors, `open` starts retuning `-1`, which because of `if (fd != -1) {` makes the program stop outputting anything.

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk. You're correct. I fixed the reader and updated in the question session. Thank you so much

Comment: `UPDATE: This is the correct main function for the reader:` Och no, that's horror. Just `open(...); while (1) { read();`. It's unclear why need to open in loop, just open once.